# Body font is not changing in tailwindcss

Tags: tailwind-css

I am trying to add body font but it is not working.  I tried `@apply font-serif`, tried  `@font-face` and both. not working.
Config

```
module.exports = {
  purge: [
    './pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}',
    './components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}',
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
    fontFamily: {
      serif: ['ff-more-web-pro', 'serif'],
      body: ['ff-more-web-pro', 'serif'],
    },
  },
};
```

Global css

```
/* ./styles/globals.css */
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer base {
  body,
  html {
    @apply text-black;
    @apply font-serif;
  }

  @font-face {
    font-family: ff-more-web-pro, serif;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 300;
  }
}
```

Using `font-body` class directly on any element in html works. Also  `@apply text-black` in `@layer base` also works and is applied to all.

Comment: Did you add the file in your tailwind.config.js file? if it's not add to the "content" section, the compiler will not attach the style to the .css